# basis for the set of parallel vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I fix a vector $v$ in $\Bbb R^3$, how would I find a basis for the set of vectors $w$ whose cross product with $v$ is zero?

I know it is the set of vectors parallel to $v$ ($+$ the zero vector). Does this mean that all such vectors are scalar multiples so a basis is simply $v$ itself?

Comment: Suggestion: if you are in doubt, try an example.  $\vec v=(1,0,0)$ say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If two vectors are parallel then one vector is a scalar multiple of the other, and the converse is also true.

Hence we have that $v$ forms a basis for the vector space consisting of all vectors having zero cross product with $v$, since the set is *exactly* the span of $v$.

Comment: Thanks. So is the definition of parallel vectors actually that they are scalar multiples?

Comment: Yes. The point is, we assume that vectors originate at zero, don't we? So we translate both vectors to the origin. Now, parallellity means that they lie along the same line passing through the origin, or that their cross product is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of basis ask them to be linear independent, which means that each vector in the basis set can't be expressed as the linear combination of the rest.
But if you choose to use two parallel vectors $\vec{v_1}~and~\vec{v_2}$ to be in the same set of basis.
From the definition of parallel we can find that there exist a number c that $\vec{v_2}=c\vec{v_1}$, this is just a linear combination which against the definition of linear independent which is also the central characteristic of basis.